# Kotlin Flow: receiving values until emitting timeout

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to collect specific amount of values from Flow until value emitting timeout happened. Unfortunately, there are no such operators, so I've tried to implement my own using `debounce` operator.

The first problem is that producer is too fast and some packages are skipped and not collected at all (they are in `onEach` of original `packages` flow, but not in `onEach` of second flow of `merge` in `withNullOnTimeout`).

The second problem - after taking last value according to `amount` argument orginal flow is closed, but timeout flow still alive and finally produce timeout after last value.

How can I solve this two problems?

My implementations:

```
suspend fun receive(packages: Flow<ByteArray>, amount: Int): ByteArray {
        val buffer = ByteArrayOutputStream(blockSize.toInt())
        packages
            .take(10)
            .takeUntilTimeout(100) // <-- custom timeout operator
            .collect { pck ->
                buffer.write(pck.data)
            }
    return buffer.toByteArray()
}

fun <T> Flow<T>.takeUntilTimeout(durationMillis: Long): Flow<T> {
    require(durationMillis > 0) { "Duration should be greater than 0" }
    return withNullOnTimeout(durationMillis)
        .takeWhile { it != null }
        .mapNotNull { it }
}

fun <T> Flow<T>.withNullOnTimeout(durationMillis: Long): Flow<T?> {
    require(durationMillis > 0) { "Duration should be greater than 0" }
    return merge(
        this,
        map<T, T?> { null }
            .onStart { emit(null) }
            .debounce(durationMillis)
    )
}
```

Comment: How is `takeUntilTimeout` supposed to behave? When is the timer supposed to start exactly?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```kotlin
fun <T> Flow<T>.takeUntilTimeout(timeoutMillis: Long) = channelFlow {
    val collector = launch {
        collect {
            send(it)
        }
        close()
    }
    delay(timeoutMillis)
    collector.cancel()
    close()
}
```

Using a `channelFlow` allows you to spawn a second coroutine so you can count the time independently, and quite simply.

Answer (score 2):

This was what initially seemed obvious to me, but as Joffrey points out in the comments, it can cause an unnecessary delay before collection terminates. I'll leave this as an example of a suboptimal, oversimplified solution.

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.takeUntilTimeout(durationMillis: Long): Flow<T> = flow {
    val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + durationMillis
    takeWhile { System.currentTimeMillis() >= endTime }
        .collect { emit(it) }
}
```

Here's an alternate idea I didn't test.

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T> Flow<T>.takeUntilTimeout(durationMillis: Long): Flow<T> {
    val signal = Any()
    return merge(flow { delay(durationMillis); emit(signal) })
        .takeWhile { it !== signal } as Flow<T>
}
```

Comment: I think a drawback of this would be that you need to have an element from the source flow in order to detect the timeout. So if the original flow emits every 10 seconds, and your timeout is 1s, you'll need to wait for another 9s before the flow stops

Comment: More importantly the timer start is wrong I believe, because the flow is supposed to be cold. Here the operator will immediately compute the current time. This of course depends on the OP's requirements, but I think it would be inappropriate as a general flow operator

Comment: Oh, right. I started with a `flow` builder and oversimplified down to what I put here. I fixed it.